# In SonarQube, How to reference a folder located in Continuous Integration tool's server?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

In sonarQube, how to reference the unit test report residing in the server pertaining to Continuous Integration tool? Please note that the sonarQube and CI tools are in different servers. This is needed to show unit test coverage in sonarQube.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the build of a project does operations like:

1. Checkout source code
2. Build source code
3. Run unit test and generate coverage reports
4. Run a SonarQube Scanner to trigger the analysis

All this happens within the CI server. This means that you just need to configure your SonarQube analysis to point to the local coverage report files that have been generate just before.

For example, take a look at the following project:

- [Sample project that reads coverage reports](https://github.com/SonarSource/sq-com_example_standard-sqscanner-travis)
- , and especially to its [sonar-project.properties](https://github.com/SonarSource/sq-com_example_standard-sqscanner-travis/blob/master/sonar-project.properties) file, in which you will see that coverage report files are referenced using relative paths.